# Using an unspecified index error appear after already set index rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

[image: Please check database structure on the attached image.]

I have rules set up like this:

```
 {
 "rules": {
 ".read": true,
 ".write": true,
 "ares": {
   "user":{
      "$user_id": {
               ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
           },
     "admin":{
       "owner":{
          ".indexOn": ".value",
        }
     }
   }
    }
   }
 }
```

I want to get owner data by owner_id, but I get this warning:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "owner_id" at /ares/user/admin/owner/ares/user/admin/owner/bD1kYczs51bdFbJKPxOTKPpQR6i2 to your security rules for better performance.

Comment: Please post the query you're using that causes this warning

Comment: You see to be nesting `/ares/user/admin/owner` twice in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that are nothing wrong with the index itself, but the value you ar trying to query.

Pay attention that the entire path /ares/user/admin/owner appears to be duplicated. You are appending this to the firebase reference.

I think that the correct reference/query should be something like this /ares/user/admin/owner/bD1kYczs51bdFbJKPxOTKPpQR6i2.